# Get folder path from sheet to count files inside that folder in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the following code which returns the number of files in a folder.

```
Sub sample()

    Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
    FolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Santosh\Desktop"

    path = FolderPath & "\*.xls"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("Q8").Value = count
    'MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"
End Sub
```

I need to parametrize `FolderPath` as an input in the excel sheet itself so that I enter the folder path in Cell A1 and get the no of files in B1. I'm pretty new to Excel Macros - excuse if this is very basic. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send folderPath string from the cell A1 in the following way:

```
Sub sample()

    Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
    FolderPath = Range("A1")

    path = FolderPath & "\*.xls"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("B1").Value = count
    MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"

End Sub
```

Put your folder path in cell A1 and run the macro.

you will get count in B1 cell

**EDIT**

For looping over all folder Paths filled in column A1,A2,A3... and getting count in corresponding cell that is B1,B2,B3...Proceed like below:

Get total rows in which folder path has been filled

```
TotalRows = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then loop from 1 to total Rows filled in column A.

```
Sub sample()

    Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
    Dim TotalRows As Integer

    TotalRows = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To TotalRows
    count = 0
    FolderPath = Range("A" & i)

    path = FolderPath & "\*.xls"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("B" & i).Value = count
    'MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton - this worked. In case I need to fill in multiple folder paths in A column and get the corresponding numbers of files in B column in one go? Where do I change it?

Comment: see edited answer for multiple folder paths in A and count in column B. @SriramIlango

Answer (score 0):

Considering your macro is working fine all you need to do is to convert your `Sub` into `Function` in this way:

```
Function FileCounter(FolderPath as String)

    Dim path As String, count As Integer

    path = FolderPath & "\*.xls"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    FileCounter = count

End Function
```

Next, in Excel do as required and type in A1 folder path and in B1 `=FileCounter(A1)`

Please note that you get number of files with `.xls` extension only but not `.xlsx`, `.xlsm` and others. To include all Excel files in results you need to change extension patern to `\*.xls*`.